# Genus of a curve? (Mirror Symmetry book)

Tags: complex-numbers, mirror-symmetry

I'm reading Chapter 6 of Mirror Symmetry book.

In Example 6.1.1
"A degree 3 polynomial f in $\mathbb P^2$ determines a curve of genus
$g = \binom{3−1}{2} = 1$ that has the structure (induced from $\mathbb P^2$) of a complex manifold."

My question is what is genus? and why is it ${}_{3-1}C_2$ in this case?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_%28mathematics%29

Comment: This wikipedia page says g=\frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}}-s. I knew what the genus is. My questions was why it is calculated by binomial coefficients.

Comment: *I knew what the genus is.* Then why did you write “what is genus?”.

Comment: The theorem is that the genus of a non-singular curve of degree $d$ in $\Bbb P^2$ is $\frac12(d-1)(d-2)$. See texts on algebraic geometry for the proof.

Comment: Also, $\frac12 (d-1)(d-2) = \binom{d-1}{2}$.